How to simulate wind while not using hair particle?
I have made a scene with a grass and flowers on the ground. And I want to make them affected by wind. All I know for making a simulation you can use turbulence and wind in case if I'm using Hair Particle. But, in this scene the grass and flowers scattering using Geometry Node. Because my ground was made by Shader Editor. So, is that possible to make wind with Geometry Node and not using Hair Particle?
For more information about the project, you can download here. Download for more information about the project
These are Geometry Nodes that I used for scattering grass:


The flowers have the same Geometry Nodes with grass for scattering.
So, is that possible to make simulation wind while using Geometry Nodes? or there an alternative way to achieve that?

Are you looking for large wind turbulent structures (like big eddies affecting in a coherent way all the grass and flower patches in an area), or would you be happy with just some random/chaotic motion ? Because you are using instances, there are some limits to what can be done without realizing these.
